# CONVERT is presenting the wrong year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2014, and I'm trying to perform a data conversion, the value being passed '04-SEP-44'

Since this was the birth year, it needs to be 1944, not 2044.

I've tried

```
select convert(DATETIME, '04-SEP-44')
select convert(DATETIME, '04-SEP-44', 1)
select convert(DATETIME, '04-SEP-44', 13)
```

But they are all using the year as **2044**.

Are there any quick fixes to this issue?

Comment: Use 4 digits for years. It's not the 20th century anymore; learn from its mistakes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibilities:

- If the value is greater than today subtract 100 years...
- Force "19" into the string...

But it really depends on your business rules, is it always going to be 1900, or could some dates be early 2000's? You should really update your front end to capture the full date.

```
select case when Y.[Value] > getdate() then dateadd(year, -100, Y.[Value]) else Y.[Value] end
  , convert(date, substring(X.[Value], 1, 7) + '19' + substring(X.[Value], 8, 2))
from (values ('04-SEP-44')) as X ([Value])
cross apply (values (convert(date, X.[Value]))) as Y ([Value]);
```

Note: why would you convert a `date` to a `datetime`? Don't use a `datetime` if you don't have a time component.

Comment: Code presented was 10 years off....   but i got the picture,    thank you!!    not my existing schema to mess with.

Comment: I thought we learned after Y2K that 2-digit years are evil. The behavior can be controlled by a [configuration option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-two-digit-year-cutoff-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15).